# Passing Action Creators to Redux combineReducers()

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm thinking about using the "[Ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)" module pattern with a Redux/React application. I think the pattern is passing both reducers and action creators to Redux's `combineReducers()` method, and I'd like to understand why that works. From the Ducks documentation:

```
// widgets.js

// Actions
const LOAD   = 'my-app/widgets/LOAD';

// Reducer
export default function reducer(state = {}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // do reducer stuff
    default: return state;
  }
}

// Action Creators
export function loadWidgets() {
  return { type: LOAD };
}
```

And then combining the reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as reducers from './ducks/index';

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
export default rootReducer;
```

Why does this work with the action creators passed in as well as the reducer as an argument to `combineReducers()`? The [API documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) gives a function signature of:

```
combineReducers(reducers)
```

and says that `reducers` must be "An object whose values correspond to different reducing functions that need to be combined into one". It says that `combineReducers()` "will check your reducers by passing undefined to them", and the rules that reducers must follow include that "If the `state` given to it is `undefined`, it must return the initial state for this specific reducer".

The action creators are clearly not returning the initial state during this test, and this pattern (Ducks) has become popular with Redux. What am I missing? Is it relying on undocumented behavior to only use the `default` method of the passed-in object? That doesn't seem to be the behavior the Redux documentation suggests.

Comment: "Earlier documentation suggested the use of the ES6 import * as reducers syntax to obtain the reducers object. This was the source of a lot of confusion, which is why we now recommend exporting a single reducer obtained using combineReducers() from reducers/index.js instead."

Comment: @Héctor that makes sense for the root reducer (and chain used to build the root reducer). But it seems to me like the Ducks pattern wouldn't work at all - the action creators would get called as reducers (and passed the `state` and `action`), and would then fail since they're not returning a valid state object.

Comment: I think the undocumented part is what's in './ducks/index.js', which is probably something like:
`import widgetsReducer from './widgets';`
`export { widgetsReducer };`